# HTML Buttons Clicks sequential or parallel?

Tags: javascript, html

Is the click handling/detection for html buttons sequential or parallel? I already googled this topic but didn't find any usefull articles.

Comment: they put an event on the event loop...

Comment: can you show your code sample, so some one can explain on the basis of that

Comment: Its a general question you have the option to register a callback function in a button or do some other stuff by default without frameworks, so the problem can be explained without example code.

Comment: The opposite of asynchronous is synchronous, not sequential.

Comment: JavaScript  is single threaded, so its sequential. Try putting an infinite loop in the handler function you should get page not responding message from browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article at MDN describes the event loop very well:

> Each message is processed completely before any other message is processed. This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 1):

"asynchronous" means "Does something later, in response to something".

A click event listener causes something to happen later, in response to a click.

It is therefore asynchronous.

Comment: No no you understood something wrong. Asynchronous in terms of parallel programming means that the programm flow isnt executed sequentially, but multiple things are executed parallel. I think you understood what I meant in the question :).